# how do we escape json data inside of a logic app?

Tags: c#, .net, json, azure-logic-apps

**Is it possible to escape json data inside of a logic app?**

For example, let's say I have a variable that looks like this:

```
{"alex":"http://www.isawesome.com"}
```

The result I'd like to have would be something like this:

```
{\"alex\":\"http:\/\/www.isawesome.com\"}
```

**How do we escape json data?**

Comment: Is there a specific requirement to do so ? why ?

Comment: You could refer to this [issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e5dee958-09a7-4784-b1bf-facdd6b8a568/post-json-from-logic-app-how-to-escape-data?forum=azurelogicapps).

Comment: Well, why are you doing this?  If you escape it, it's not JSON anymore.  Meaning, if you have to do this, it's quite possible you're doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a function / action that does this.

If so, you can simply use the [`string`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#string) function available.

Answer (score 0):

Logic Apps supports Expressions where you may use the Replace function. Dynamic content may be used in place of a static string.

```
replace('http://www.isawesome.com', '/', '\/')
```

[image: Logic Apps Interface to add an Expression]

The expression can be added to any input where you want to buildout the Json

[image: How the expression will look in the input window]